# +1 a Google+ post using +1 Button, not the page the post is on

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

Basically we're pulling in posts from Google+ via the API and displaying them on the front-end of our website.
Initially, I thought there'd be a way to +1 a post via Google's API but that doesn't seem to be possible.

My question is:

**Is there a way to +1 a Google+ post via the +1 Button?** (https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/)

When I add the post link as the href to be +1'd, clicking the button seems to +1 the page the post is on and not the post that I want to +1.

e.g:

```
<div data-href="https://plus.google.com/105006372004430064055/posts/J8ByfBamiGf" class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div>
```

A potential though undesirable solution is to use Embedded Posts (https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/) but then I don't have control over styling and layout.

Comment: Have you tried setting `data-href` to the post permalink?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I have. 
The `https://plus.google.com/105006372004430064055/posts/J8ByfBamiGf` url in data-href is the permalink to that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1's of a URL and +1's of a Google+ post are tallied separately.

You can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) if you would like to see better integration.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Cheers.